# How to retrieve a value from firebase within a table?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let me start by showing what I have and what I have tried so far:

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Datah/Real');
    database.orderByChild("result").equalTo("RUNNING").once('value', function(snapshot){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
          var key = data.ref.getKey();
          var time = data.val().time;
          var quote = data.val().quote;
          var type = data.val().type;

          var date = new Date(time * 1000);

          var current = 0;
          firebase.database().ref().child("Datah/Prices/" + quote).once("value", function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.key+" : "+snapshot.child("price").val());
            current = snapshot.child("price").val();
          });

          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<td>' + date.toLocaleString() + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + quote + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + type + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + current + '</td>';
          content += '</tr>';
        });

        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
        var tbody = $('table tbody');
        tbody.html($('tr',tbody).get().reverse());
       });
```

I have data in firebase which I am retrieving from the first ref: ***Datah/Real***, and this data contains a string value under *quote*, For each data I am retrieving I want to use *quote* to retrieve related data from another ref: ***Datah/Prices***. In that ref I want to retrieve only data from a child equal to *quote*, therefore: ***Datah/Prices/quote***. When I get this value I want to populate my table with it.

I managed to get first data and it is populating my table correctly, the challenge is on the second snapshot which should return *current*, because it still returns **0** as predefine, however on the console: `console.log(snapshot.key+" : "+snapshot.child("price").val());` It is showing that it is actually retrieving the value, but why on my table *current* is always **0** and not **0** on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is because the code runs asynchronously

This code is correctly getting the current price, but only AFTER the rest of the code has run.

```
firebase.database()
.ref("Datah/Prices/" + quote)
.once("value", 
      snapshot=>{
          // This code is asynchronous, i.e. only runs after this snapshot has been returned, 
          // which will be long after the "content =" lines in your code
              console.log(snapshot.key+" : "+snapshot.child("price").val());
          current = snapshot.child("price").val();


          // Therefore try putting all the `content += ` code in here.
          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<td>' + date.toLocaleString() + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + quote + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + type + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + current + '</td>';
          content += '</tr>';
          $('#ex-table').append(content);
      }
);
```

To solve this, how about moving all the table updates to AFTER the "current = snapshot...", which means it must be INSIDE the asynchronous code block, as I show above.

You might still need to fiddle with the code a bit to make the jQuery updates happen - I am not familiar with jQuery so I might not have moved *exactly* the right code inside the block.

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to indicate that I tried that also (to put table content inside that method) and the table was completely empty,

Comment: DId you make sure to put the ` $('#ex-table').append(content);` inside that method, also? As shown in my code? Because even if `current` was 0, surely it would have shown the date and the 0? If it didn't, it was probably because you didn't tell it to append the content at that point.

Comment: awesome,  I had not moved the table with: $('#ex-table').append(content); Now it works, you saved a life sir

Comment: A quick one, if that current value changes in firebase its not updating on my table unless I refresh the table, what would be a quick solution to that?

Comment: Try "on" instead of "once"?

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is everytime a value changes the rows multiply, and as a value keeps on changing the rows keeps on multiplying to an extend that I will end up having a million rows instead of 1 as I have only one currently